# Python Regex Code not working for more than 5 iterations

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-negation, regex-group

This is a hackerrank problem which i have tried to solve .
The Problem statement was:

You and Fredrick are good friends. Yesterday, Fredrick received  credit cards from ABCD Bank. He wants to verify whether his credit card numbers are valid or not. You happen to be great at regex so he is asking for your help!
A valid credit card from ABCD Bank has the following characteristics:

1. It must start with a ,  or .
2. It must contain exactly  digits.
3. It must only consist of digits (-).
4. It may have digits in groups of , separated by one hyphen "-".
5. It must NOT use any other separator like ' ' , '_', etc.
6. It must NOT have  or more consecutive repeated digits.

Input Format
The first line of input contains an integer . 
The next  lines contain credit card numbers.
Constraints

Output Format
Print 'Valid' if the credit card number is valid. Otherwise, print 'Invalid'. Do not print the quotes.

The solution which I scipted is:

```
 import re
```

for _ in range(int(input())):
    cc_inp=input()

```
reg=re.findall(r'(^[456]{1}\d{3})(?! _)(-?)(\d{4})(?! _)(-?)(\d{4})(?! _)(-?)(\d{4})$',cc_inp)
if reg:
    reg1=re.sub(r'\D', "",cc_inp)

    for i in range(13):
        if(reg1[i]==reg1[i+1]):
            if(reg1[i+1]==reg1[i+2]):
                if(reg1[i+2]==reg1[i+3]):
                    print("Invalid")
                    exit()                   
        else:
            res=True
    if(res==True):
        print("Valid")

else:
    print("Invalid")
```

For Test Case:

6

4123456789123456

5123-4567-8912-3456

61234-567-8912-3456

4123356789123456

5133-3367-8912-3456

5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456

It is giving Output only for first 5 test case:
Valid

Valid

Invalid

Valid

Invalid

The 6th case is not being executed,when i try to execute 6th case separately ,it gets executed and displays the desired output.

**EDIT:**
I am mentioning the link to this problem, this is just online practicing problem,not for any competition.

[Hackerrank-Validating Credit Card Numbers](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validating-credit-card-number/problem)

Comment: Is this a *running* competition?

Comment: Your rules aren't clear, I think you're missing information.

Comment: Please show how you feed the test cases to your code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No,its not a Competition,just a practice problem.

Comment: @ctwheels I have mentioned the link to the problem,hope it provides the required information.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson After running the script ,compiler waits for input ,where i had entered:                        
6

4123456789123456

5123-4567-8912-3456

61234-567-8912-3456

4123356789123456

5133-3367-8912-3456

5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456

in this the first input 6 is the number of credit card numbers i would give the script to validate followed by the credit card numbers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the beginning of the loop, since it was not marked as code. And your indentation is confusing. The code exits at one point where an entry is judged invalid; that's why the last one isn't read.

Comment: All digits seem to be lost from your specification, for example: "It must contain exactly digits".

Comment: the input is fed by the hackerrank website in following indentation:
6

4123456789123456

5123-4567-8912-3456

61234-567-8912-3456

4123356789123456

5133-3367-8912-3456

5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456
In the link which i have provided ,there sample input is mentioned,for proper indentation please refer it if you can,Thankyou.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson Could you please check this link, https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/validating-credit-card-number/problem
I hope this will make my question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/hJScsE/2)

```
^(?!.*?(\d)(?:\D?\1){3})[4-6]\d{3}(?:-?\d{4}){3}$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!.*?(\d)(?:\D?\1){3})` Negative lookahead ensuring the following doesn't match

  - `.*?` Match any character any number of times, but as few as possible
  - `(\d)` Capture a single digit into capture group 1
  - `(?:\D?\1){3}` Match the following exactly 3 times

    - `\D?` Optionally match a non-digit character
    - `\1` Match the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
- `[4-6]` Matches any digit in the range from 4 to 6
- `\d{3}` Match any 3 digits
- `(?:-?\d{4}){3}` Match the following exactly 3 times

  - `-?` Optionally match `-`
  - `\d{4}` Match any 4 digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

The negative lookahead in the above code optionally matches `\D` so that the negative lookahead will filter out entries like `33-33` where the `3` is repeated 4 times consecutively.

---

#### Code

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##fZDRaoMwFIavzVNkdhdxLLLkJFELw5u9Re1AqqWBViXKcIw@u8up88IWBgk5@f6fc/6k@x5ObQPTZC9d6wbqakJK@k53JAiV1GCkTpPMCJ2kJnwNlZLLum2PtJCSSzApTzKtOEiBVAkJSpskzeZiNgJHxhHyP4pGWBnp5qs828oHuOl3IZIlhfonBeV0yYGGcWV90@uWHhmcze@jaQHAAR6oBOzv3f5ABW8rTT1qdGOb@Vl74vz/ujo@tJfOnmvmwk@WP8UvOSuqiOXb4iMvRPQD12inuNkXlS895rmv1BWF5zAi5Ng62lPb0HJLghFbxn1dusOJ9REJ7JGOngeds83gyTT9Ag)

```
import re

a = [
    "4253625879615786","4424424424442444","5122-2368-7954-3214","4123456789123456","5123-4567-8912-3456","4123356789123456", #valid
    "6","42536258796157867","4424444424442444","5122-2368-7954 - 3214","44244x4424442444","0525362587961578","61234-567-8912-3456","5133-3367-8912-3456","5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456","5123 - 4567 - 8912 - 3456" #invalid
]
r = re.compile(r"^(?!.*?(\d)(?:\D?\1){3})[4-6]\d{3}(?:-?\d{4}){3}$")

for s in a:
    x = r.search(s)
    if x:
        print(s)
```

---

#### Results

Matches/Output:

```
4253625879615786
4424424424442444
5122-2368-7954-3214
4123456789123456
5123-4567-8912-3456
4123356789123456
```

Does not match:

```
6                          # Not 16 digits long
42536258796157867          # Is 17 digits long
4424444424442444           # Contains 44444 (4+ repetition)
5122-2368-7954 - 3214      # Contains spaces around last hyphen
44244x4424442444           # Contains non-digit character x
0525362587961578           # Does not start with 4-6
61234-567-8912-3456        # Length of first and second parts is not 4
5133-3367-8912-3456        # Contains 33-33 (4+ repetition)
5123 - 3567 - 8912 - 3456  # Contains spaces around hyphens
5123 - 4567 - 8912 - 3456  # Contains spaces around hyphens
```

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
       if(reg1[i+2]==reg1[i+3]):
            print("Invalid")
            exit()
```

gets run for one of your examples, and then program exits, as you told it. That's why it doesn't try the last example.